# PHP creating XML is inserting extra tags and extraneous data. Help?

Tags: php, xml, excel

I'm trying to import XML data from an excel spreadsheet (saved as an 'XML Spreadsheet 2003').  The PHP script reads the excel data, and then transposes the data to an external XML file.  This new file, in turn is read by a javscript to place markers on a google map using the google map API.  I know this is inefficient, but the goal is to give the client a spreadsheet they can easily edit and upload, and have those changes reflected on the site without any intervention from me.

The issues are as follows:

- The script duplicates the last excel
  entry twice (creating 3 xml entries
  of the same data)
- The cells which    contain numbers
  have extra zeros    placed in the
  middle of the number (excel does this)
- The header row of the excel file is
  being included in the XML, despite my
  attempt otherwise
- The URL attribute    of the XML
  should be blank if it is    not
  provided, but the xml reads 'URL'

Screenshot of Excel showing how data is entered:
Correction, no images for noobs like me.  Click for a screen shot: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0pgS.jpg)

Source of Excel XML spreadsheet (I included all of it in case I'm missing something):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <Author>Brandon</Author>
  <LastAuthor>Brandon</LastAuthor>
  <Created>2011-04-01T21:05:56Z</Created>
  <Version>14.00</Version>
 </DocumentProperties>
 <OfficeDocumentSettings xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <AllowPNG/>
 </OfficeDocumentSettings>
 <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
  <WindowHeight>7995</WindowHeight>
  <WindowWidth>20115</WindowWidth>
  <WindowTopX>240</WindowTopX>
  <WindowTopY>75</WindowTopY>
  <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
  <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
 </ExcelWorkbook>
 <Styles>
  <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
   <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s62">
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Bold="1"/>
  </Style>
 </Styles>
 <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="9" ss:ExpandedRowCount="4" x:FullColumns="1"
   x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
   <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="86.25"/>
   <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="128.25"/>
   <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="156.75"/>
   <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="112.5"/>
   <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="103.5"/>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String">Lat</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String">Long</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String">Name</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String">Phone</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String">Address</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String">City</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String">State</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String">Zip</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String">URL</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">39.769831000000003</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">-104.972657</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Generic Liquors</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">555-123-5555</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">42 Walnut St</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Denver</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">CO</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">80207</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">39.763903999999997</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">-104.966311</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Fancy Restaurant</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">555-123-5556</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">55 Colfax Drive</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Denver</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">CO</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">80207</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">39.759087000000001</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">-104.982963</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Even Fancier Restaurant</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">555-123-5557</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">1129 Boggio St</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Denver</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">CO</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">87505</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
  </Table>
  <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
   <PageSetup>
    <Header x:Margin="0.3"/>
    <Footer x:Margin="0.3"/>
    <PageMargins x:Bottom="0.75" x:Left="0.7" x:Right="0.7" x:Top="0.75"/>
   </PageSetup>
   <Unsynced/>
   <Selected/>
   <Panes>
    <Pane>
     <Number>3</Number>
     <ActiveRow>4</ActiveRow>
     <ActiveCol>4</ActiveCol>
    </Pane>
   </Panes>
   <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>
   <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>
  </WorksheetOptions>
 </Worksheet>
 <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet2">
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="1" ss:ExpandedRowCount="1" x:FullColumns="1"
   x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0"/>
  </Table>
  <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
   <PageSetup>
    <Header x:Margin="0.3"/>
    <Footer x:Margin="0.3"/>
    <PageMargins x:Bottom="0.75" x:Left="0.7" x:Right="0.7" x:Top="0.75"/>
   </PageSetup>
   <Unsynced/>
   <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>
   <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>
  </WorksheetOptions>
 </Worksheet>
 <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet3">
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="1" ss:ExpandedRowCount="1" x:FullColumns="1"
   x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0"/>
  </Table>
  <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
   <PageSetup>
    <Header x:Margin="0.3"/>
    <Footer x:Margin="0.3"/>
    <PageMargins x:Bottom="0.75" x:Left="0.7" x:Right="0.7" x:Top="0.75"/>
   </PageSetup>
   <Unsynced/>
   <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>
   <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>
  </WorksheetOptions>
 </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

Excel XML source of just the relevant cell data:

```
<Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String">Lat</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String">Long</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String">Name</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String">Phone</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String">Address</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String">City</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String">State</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String">Zip</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String">URL</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">39.769831000000003</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">-104.972657</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Generic Liquors</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">555-123-5555</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">42 Walnut St</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Denver</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">CO</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">80207</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">39.763903999999997</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">-104.966311</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Fancy Restaurant</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">555-123-5556</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">55 Colfax Drive</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Denver</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">CO</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">80207</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">39.759087000000001</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">-104.982963</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Even Fancier Restaurant</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">555-123-5557</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">1129 Boggio St</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Denver</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">CO</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">87505</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
```

PHP Script:

```
<?php
//
// Read the Excel File
    $data = array();
    //format the array values
    function add_marker( $lat, $long, $name, $phone, $address, $city, $state, $zip, $url )
    {
    global $data;

    $data []= array(
    'Lat' => $lat,
    'Long' => $long,
    'Name' => $name,
    'Phone' => $phone,
    'Address' => $address,
    'City' => $city,
    'State' => $state,
    'Zip' => $zip,
    'URL' => $url 
    );
    }
    // Load the spreadsheet
    $dom = DOMDocument::load( '/home/public/xml/tour.xml' );
    // Select XML tag in the spreadsheet to use
    $rows = $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'Row' );
    $first_row = true;
    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
    if ( !$first_row )
    {
    $lat = "";
    $long = "";
    $name = "";
    $phone = "";
    $address = "";
    $city = "";
    $state = "";
    $zip = "";
    $url = "";

    $index = 1;
    $cells = $row->getElementsByTagName( 'Cell' );
    foreach( $cells as $cell )
    { 
    $ind = $cell->getAttribute( 'Index' );
    if ( $ind != null ) $index = $ind;

    if ( $index == 1 ) $lat = $cell->nodeValue;
    if ( $index == 2 ) $long = $cell->nodeValue;
    if ( $index == 3 ) $name = $cell->nodeValue;
    if ( $index == 4 ) $phone = $cell->nodeValue;
    if ( $index == 5 ) $address = $cell->nodeValue;
    if ( $index == 6 ) $city = $cell->nodeValue;
    if ( $index == 7 ) $state = $cell->nodeValue;
    if ( $index == 8 ) $zip = $cell->nodeValue;
    if ( $index == 9 ) $url = $cell->nodeValue;

    $index += 1;
    }
    add_marker( $lat, $long, $name, $phone, $address, $city, $state, $zip, $url );
    }
    $first_row = false;
    }
//
// Write and save xml file
//
    //create document
    $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    //pretty formatting
    $doc->formatOutput = true;

    //create 'markers' root element
    $root = $doc->createElement('markers');
    $doc->appendChild($root);

    //run through the array constructed from excel file
    foreach( $data as $row )
    {
        //create individual marker element
        $root_child = $doc->createElement('marker');
        $root->appendChild($root_child);

        //set attribute of lat
        $root_attr1 = $doc->createAttribute('lat');
        $root_child->appendChild($root_attr1);
        //assign 'lat' attribute it's value from array
        $root_text = $doc->createTextNode($row['Lat']);
        $root_attr1->appendChild($root_text);

        //set attribute of lng
        $root_attr2= $doc->createAttribute('lng');
        $root_child->appendChild($root_attr2);
        //assign 'lng' attribute it's value from array
        $root_text = $doc->createTextNode($row['Long']);
        $root_attr2->appendChild($root_text);

        //set attribute of name
        $root_attr3= $doc->createAttribute('name');
        $root_child->appendChild($root_attr3);
        //assign 'name' attribute it's value from array
        $root_text = $doc->createTextNode($row['Name']);
        $root_attr3->appendChild($root_text);

        //set attribute of phone
        $root_attr4= $doc->createAttribute('phone');
        $root_child->appendChild($root_attr4);
        //assign 'phone' attribute it's value from array
        $root_text = $doc->createTextNode($row['Phone']);
        $root_attr4->appendChild($root_text);

        //set attribute of address
        $root_attr5= $doc->createAttribute('address');
        $root_child->appendChild($root_attr5);
        //assign 'address' attribute it's value from array
        $root_text = $doc->createTextNode($row['Address']);
        $root_attr5->appendChild($root_text);

        //set attribute of city
        $root_attr6= $doc->createAttribute('city');
        $root_child->appendChild($root_attr6);
        //assign 'city' attribute it's value from array
        $root_text = $doc->createTextNode($row['City']);
        $root_attr6->appendChild($root_text);

        //set attribute of state
        $root_attr7= $doc->createAttribute('state');
        $root_child->appendChild($root_attr7);
        //assign 'state' attribute it's value from array
        $root_text = $doc->createTextNode($row['State']);
        $root_attr7->appendChild($root_text);

        //set attribute of zip
        $root_attr8= $doc->createAttribute('zip');
        $root_child->appendChild($root_attr8);
        //assign 'zip' attribute it's value from array
        $root_text = $doc->createTextNode($row['Zip']);
        $root_attr8->appendChild($root_text);

        //set attribute of url
        $root_attr9= $doc->createAttribute('url');
        $root_child->appendChild($root_attr9);
        //assign 'name' attribute it's value from array
        $root_text = $doc->createTextNode($row['URL']);
        $root_attr9->appendChild($root_text);
    }

    $doc->save("/home/public/xml/markers.xml");//save("/home/public/xml/markers.xml");
?>
```

Output of the markers.xml file:

```
<markers>
  <marker lat="Lat" lng="Long" name="Name" phone="Phone" address="Address" city="City" state="State" zip="Zip" url="URL"/>
  <marker lat="39.769831000000003" lng="-104.972657" name="Generic Liquors" phone="555-123-5555" address="42 Walnut St" city="Denver" state="CO" zip="80207" url="URL"/>
  <marker lat="39.763903999999997" lng="-104.966311" name="Fancy Restaurant" phone="555-123-5556" address="55 Colfax Drive" city="Denver" state="CO" zip="80207" url="URL"/>
  <marker lat="39.759087000000001" lng="-104.982963" name="Even Fancier Restaurant" phone="555-123-5557" address="1129 Boggio St" city="Denver" state="CO" zip="87505" url="URL"/>
  <marker lat="39.759087000000001" lng="-104.982963" name="Even Fancier Restaurant" phone="555-123-5557" address="1129 Boggio St" city="Denver" state="CO" zip="87505" url="URL"/>
  <marker lat="39.759087000000001" lng="-104.982963" name="Even Fancier Restaurant" phone="555-123-5557" address="1129 Boggio St" city="Denver" state="CO" zip="87505" url="URL"/>
</markers>
```

Lots of extra numbers and extra marker tags in there.  Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem #1:**

> The script duplicates the last excel entry twice (creating 3 xml entries of the same data)

Could be related to the fact that there is a blank row in the second worksheet. Restrict your code to the rows in the first worksheet only because you're still calling add_marker() even if there are no cells in the row. If you don't restrrict to just the first worksheet, then you can do

```
if ($index > 1)
    add_marker( $lat, $long, $name, $phone, $address, $city, $state, $zip, $url );
```

instead of just

```
add_marker( $lat, $long, $name, $phone, $address, $city, $state, $zip, $url );
```

**Problem #2:**

> The cells which contain numbers have extra zeros placed in the middle of the number (excel does this)

change the lines that extract this information to round the data to perhaps 6 decimal places
e.g. change

```
$lat = $cell->nodeValue;
```

to

```
$lat = round($cell->nodeValue,6);
```

**Problem #3:**

> The header row of the excel file is being included in the XML, despite my attempt otherwise

Ensure that the header is actually row 1 of the first worksheet, and the code you've provided should work correctly. If the header is in row 2 or above, or if you have any previous worksheets in the workbook, then you'll have this problem.

Comment: Thank you Mark!  Worksheets, so simple, yet those things are always looked over by me.  I deleted the other worksheets in the excel sheet, that solved the extra marker entries, and the first marker with all the blank headers.  And a pleasant surprise, the URL atrribute is now correctly being left blank.  The rounding feature also worked a treat.  Thanks Again.